# Displaying angular loading bar for non XHR requests

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular loading bar(angular-loading-bar) for all XHR requests to show the loading indicator. But how do i show the loading bar for non XHR requests.
for example, i want to show the loading bar while page navigation.

I tried to include it inside **run** block in the following way, but the loading icon not showing.

```
.run(['cfpLoadingBar',function ( cfpLoadingBar) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event) {        
    cfpLoadingBar.start();
  });
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event) {       
    cfpLoadingBar.complete();
  });
}]);
```

Comment: It has [a delay](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar#latency-threshold). What are the chances that state change is long enough?

Comment: @estus, actually it is working for XHR requests but not showing the loader for non XHR requests i.e page transitions using $state.go(), I am getting 5sec delay while moving one page to another.

Comment: Did you add the [loading bar service](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar#service-api-advanced-usage) as a dependency?

Comment: @marton, i added one simple test page with no data and it is working fine(showing loading icon) but if i add existing page(multi step signup page) contains lot of  fields not working(taking long time to go to the page in the android tablet)